# Is there a Tablet version of Ubuntu coming up?

Tags: unity, tablet

Unity seems VERY touch friendly: large icons, high contrast etc. Could it be possible to see it on the tablet market? Since it's very hardware friendly (last I checked, some Ubuntu distros actually require LESS hardware power than android) and open, it could provide a superior tablet at an inferior cost.

Oh and it would get the Ubuntu name OUT there!

Comment: Some Ubuntu distros? If you want to say Xubuntu, Lubuntu and so on... well they don't use Unity. Ubuntu is the only "Ubuntu distro" that uses it. In fact the only difference is the RAM: Android needs 512 MiB and Ubuntu 384 MiB.

Comment: Inferior cost? android is free....

Comment: I wouldn't call Unity touch friendly just because of that side bar. It still has menus everywhere, and menus aren't finger friendly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Ubuntu is slated to [run well on tablets and other form factors](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/820) by the spring of 2014.

Answer (score 1):

There was some [speculation](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/more-details-emerge-on-mystery-ubuntu-tablet/) about the **TENQ P07** tablet that is [supposed to launch this year](http://www.gizchina.com/2010/12/28/ubuntu-tablet-details-surface/).

Via **OMG! Ubuntu**:

> The ‘TENQ P07′ tablet aims to launch
>   early next year an will sport Ubuntu
>   10.10 atop an 1.6Ghz Atom CPU, 2GB of RAM and a 32GB SSD, the manufacturers
>   told Gizchina.
>
> Rounding that out is a 10.1 inch
>   capacitive (presumably multi-touch)
>   screen, webcam, Bluetooth, WIFI, HDMI
>   out and a MicroSD reader.
>
> In a quick interview with GizChina the
>   developers behind the Tenq mentioned
>   some further exciting additions that
>   users can expect:
>
> "We're just working the kinks out of
>   the  software now, mostly just
>   brushing up the touch interface and
>   also working on the best possible on
>   screen keyboard display."

Answer (score 0):

The Italian manufacturer Ekoore produces already two Ubuntu-powered tablets: the [Perl](http://www.ekoore.com/web/en/product/tablet-2/perl-3/panoramica-10.html) and the [Python](http://www.ekoore.com/web/en/product/tablet-2/python-2/panoramica-11.html).